# Jetpack Compose Previews: No Backgrounds, No System UI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-studio-bumblebee, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I am bootstrapping a new app with Jetpack Compose and Material 3. I've created a bunch of new apps lately with this configuration, so this problem has me stuck: I cannot get the IDE's compose previews to show a background or system UI. The compiled app works great.

I tried building [this sample app with Jetpack Compose + Material 3 I created a while back](https://gitlab.com/oliverspryn/multimodal-android-app/) and all of the previews are just fine in the same version of the IDE. I also tried downgrading my libraries to match that sample app's libraries. No luck. The sample app has working previews, mine does not.

I DO have the compose UI tooling included in my Gradle script for my debug variant, and I am previewing with the debug variant.

Thoughts?

Here is what I see:

[image: IDE preview]

This is how I generate this screen code sample:

```
@Composable
fun LoadingScreen() {
    Column {
        Text("Example")
    }
}

@Preview(name = "Light Mode", showBackground = true)
@Preview(name = "Dark Mode", uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES, showBackground = true)
@Preview(name = "Full Preview", showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewLoadingScreen() {
    MyTheme {
        LoadingScreen()
    }
}
```

My theme is pretty stock for Material 3:

```
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    // ...
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    // ...
)

@Composable
fun MyTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }
        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            (view.context as Activity).window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(view)?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Here is what I am using:

- **Android Studio Bumblebee:** 2021.1.1 Patch 1
- **AGP:** 7.2.0-alpha05
- **Jetpack Compose:** 1.2.0-alpha03 (also tried 1.1.0)
- **Gradle:** 7.4
- **Kotlin:** 1.6.10
- androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha05
- com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out two things that were giving me headaches and broke the view:

1. My app was broken up into two modules, the main `app` module, and a `shared` module. The `shared` module had both the Material `com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha01` and Material 3 `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha05` libraries in the `implementation()` list in Gradle. However, my `app` module only had the Material 3 library. Including the Material library in addition in the `app` module fixed this issue.
2. Throughout this process, I learned that it is essential to have your app's theme inherit from one of the `Theme.Material3.*` base themes, and also to apply your theme to the `<application />` tag in your manifest. Android Studio will try to warn you that your `android:theme` on your `<application />` tag can be removed since it only needs to go onto an `<activity />`, but that advice is incorrect. Include your theme in both places.

Answer (score 11):

I think that your code should looks like this:

```
fun LoadingScreen() {
    Column(
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize() //this line is to set the composable like match_prent
) {
        Text("Example")
    }
}

@Preview(name = "Light Mode", showBackground = true)
@Preview(name = "Dark Mode", uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES, showBackground = true)
@Preview(name = "Full Preview", showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewLoadingScreen() {
    MyTheme {
        Surface { //Surface is like a template to see the theme configuration you need to add it
          LoadingScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just ruined my afternoon to figure out why the UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES never showed dark mode preview. I was always missing Surface Composable. Thanks man!

Comment: Is this still the case? My preview seems to be working without using the `Surface` composable.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I personally use:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFFFF)
```